# What is the closure of the set of continuous bounded real valued functions on $\mathbb{R}^d$ under pointwise convergence?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, functions, pointwise-convergence

What is the closure of the set of continuous bounded real-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}^d$ under pointwise convergence? How might one go about finding this closure? Also, are there common names for spaces of functions equipped with different notions of convergence (topologies)?

Does anyone have a comprehensive resource listing results like the closures of common function spaces with certain topologies? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such functions (pointwise sequential limits of continuous funvtions) are called Baire functions of the first class. (the second class is are the pointwise limit of those etc.), see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_function) or [this survey paper](https://www.whitman.edu/Documents/Academics/Mathematics/huh.pdf). They are quite well-studied and classical objects in topology.

It’s well-known that the continuous functions are dense in all functions on a space $X$, provided that $X$ has enough real continuous functions, e.g when $X$ is Tychonoff or even just functionally Hausdorff.  So the fact I said sequential limits is quite important.

Comment: You mean pointwise limits of SEQUENCES of continuous functions. The space of continuous functions is dense in the space of all real-valued functions in the topology of pointwiese convergence.

Comment: @Jochen true, in Tychonoff spaces.